# How to get prediction label and percentage from pipeline?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I am using the following Hugging Face transformer code.

```
from transformers import pipeline
classifier = pipeline("sentiment-analysis",model='bhadresh-savani/distilbert-base-uncased-emotion', return_all_scores=True)
prediction = classifier("I love using transformers. The best part is wide range of support and its easy to use", )
print(prediction)
```

The result is:

```
[[{'label': 'sadness', 'score': 0.010154823772609234}, {'label': 'joy', 'score': 0.5637667179107666}, {'label': 'love', 'score': 0.4066571295261383}, {'label': 'anger', 'score': 0.01734882965683937}, {'label': 'fear', 'score': 0.0011737244203686714}, {'label': 'surprise', 'score': 0.0008987095206975937}]]
```

I would like to know how can I get the highest score together with the label, but I am not sure how to iterate this object or if there is an easy way with expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a [TextClassificationPipeline](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/pipelines#transformers.TextClassificationPipeline). When you `__call__` the pipeline you get a list of `dict` if `top_k=0` or a list of list of `dict` if `top_k=None` as per the [documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/pipelines#transformers.TextClassificationPipeline.__call__).

You can either set `top_k` to `0` (the default value) and then access the values you want - in this case you will only get the score and text of the highest scoring label:

```
from transformers import pipeline
classifier = pipeline("sentiment-analysis",model='bhadresh-savani/distilbert-base-uncased-emotion', top_k=0)
prediction = classifier("I love using transformers. The best part is wide range of support and its easy to use")
print(prediction[0]["label"], prediction[0]["score"])
```

Or, if you want the scores for all labels, and then access only the highest scoring label (`top_k=0`):

```
from transformers import pipeline
classifier = pipeline("sentiment-analysis",model='bhadresh-savani/distilbert-base-uncased-emotion', top_k=None)
prediction = classifier("I love using transformers. The best part is wide range of support and its easy to use")
print(max(prediction[0], key=lambda k: k["score"]))
```